# Copy Range based on specific column value into multiple tabs in new workbook

Tags: google-apps-script

I manage a workbook in google sheets to track vendor tickets. It has one tab called "MasterTracker". The table headers are as below;

> ***Ticket Number | Issue | Description | StatusInternal | StatusVendor | Priority | Created Date | Internal Owner |    Vendor Owner |  Resolution  | Target Resolution Date |  Comments | ClosedDate***

What I'm looking to do now, is to split the data based on "StatusInternal" column (Values: Open, Hold, Future, Hold) and move data for each value in the column to a new tab in one new workbook with the name of the status as sheet names. 
For example, all ticket with open, closed, hold, future status moved to a newsheet with a sheet name "open", "closed", "hold", "future" in a new workbook and save it in a google drive.

This new workbook is sent out in an email on a daily basis and currently, I do the above-mentioned process in a manual way.

Could somebody please possibly provide me with the script or add-on to do so in Google Sheets?

Thanks ahead of time!
-Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a new Spreadsheet with three sheets (Open, Hold and Future) with the corresponding data in them.

This is what I tried:

```
function createSpreadsheets() {

  var StatusInternal = ["Open","Hold","Future"];

  //Create the new file
  var newSprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Status Internal");

  for (var i = 0; i < StatusInternal.length; i++){
    //Create the new Sheets with the Status Internal names
    newSprsheet.insertSheet(StatusInternal[i]);
  }
  //Activates the first sheet (Sheet1), to delete it, as it is not necessary
  newSprsheet.getSheets()[0].activate();
  newSprsheet.deleteActiveSheet();

  splitData(newSprsheet, StatusInternal);


}

function splitData(newSprsheet, StatusInternal){

  var mainSprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Id of your main Spreadsheet");
  var mainSheet = mainSprsheet.getActiveSheet();

  //Gets the values of the first row
  var headcolumns = mainSheet.getRange("A1:L1").getValues(); 
  //Gets the values of the Status Internal Column
  var StatusValues = mainSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues();

  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    //Copies the first row values to each new Sheet
    newSprsheet.getSheets()[i].appendRow(headcolumns[0]);
  }

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++){
    //Gets all the values of the row
    var rowContents = mainSheet.getRange("A"+i+":L"+i).getValues();
    //Appends a new row to the Sheet depending of the value in Column C.
    switch(StatusValues[i-2].toString()){

      case StatusInternal[0]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[0]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;
      case StatusInternal[1]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[1]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;
      case StatusInternal[2]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[2]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;
    }

  }
}
```

**References:**

- [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [AppendRow method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents)
- [SpreadSheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Hello Jescanellas, the solution worked like a charm! Thank you so much for writing the script :) I made some adjustments to read the correct tab as I have more than one tab in the workbook (I did mention one tab in my question whilst its more one) and I adjusted it by adding 
`var mainSheet = mainSprsheet.getSheetByName("MasterTracker");`
**I got two asks on top of the current solution;**
_1. How to preserve formatting as the new tabs with Data for different Status doesnt have any formatting like header band colour, alignment, etc_
_2. How to save the file to a folder in Google Drive?_

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! Regarding your two questions, you should open a new post as this would be very confusing to answer in the comments.

Comment: Understood, I will post another question and send you the link. Thank you!

Comment: Per your suggestion, I have created a new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58758817/how-to-retain-format-of-the-document-when-using-getvalues-function-in-gas). Thank you