# How to retain format of the sheet when using getvalues() function in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I currently have a code (shout out to @Jescanellas for crafting the code) which identifies unique values in a specific column (Column D) and creates a new spreadsheet in google sheets and puts the table header and the data related to the value in a separate sheet in the new spreadsheet. The table headers are as below;

`Ticket Number | Issue | Description | StatusInternal | StatusVendor | Priority | Created Date | Internal Owner | Vendor Owner | Resolution | Target Resolution Date | Comments | ClosedDate`

However, firstly, the code does not retain the format of the table like borders, font, alignment, header row colour, etc, in other words, its in plain text. So I would like to know the possibilities of retaining the format and how to alter the code to achieve it.

Secondly, I would like to save the new document created by the code in a specific google drive location with the naming convention of `"DocumentName_Date"`and I am not sure how to achieve that either.

> Updated Code below

```
function createSpreadsheets() {

  var StatusInternal = ["Open","Hold","Future","Closed"];

  //Create the new file
  var newSprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Status Internal");

  for (var i = 0; i < StatusInternal.length; i++){
    //Create the new Sheets with the Status Internal names
    newSprsheet.insertSheet(StatusInternal[i]);
  }
  //Activates the first sheet (Sheet1), to delete it, as it is not necessary
  newSprsheet.getSheets()[0].activate();
  newSprsheet.deleteActiveSheet();
  splitData(newSprsheet, StatusInternal);
}

function splitData(newSprsheet, StatusInternal){

  var mainSprsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("DocID");
  var mainSheet = mainSprsheet.getSheetByName("MasterTracker");

  //Gets the values of the first row
  var headcolumns = mainSheet.getRange("A1:M1").getValues(); 
  //Gets the values of the Status Internal Column
  var StatusValues = mainSheet.getRange("D2:D").getValues();

  var lastRow = mainSheet.getLastRow();

  for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    //Copies the first row values to each new Sheet
    newSprsheet.getSheets()[i].appendRow(headcolumns[0]);
  }

  for (var i = 2; i <= lastRow; i++){
    //Gets all the values of the row
    var rowContents = mainSheet.getRange("A"+i+":M"+i).getValues();
    //Appends a new row to the Sheet depending of the value in Column C.
   switch(StatusValues[i-2].toString()){

      case StatusInternal[0]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[0]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;

      case StatusInternal[1]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[1]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;

      case StatusInternal[2]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[2]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;

      case StatusInternal[3]:
        newSprsheet.getSheetByName(StatusInternal[3]).appendRow(rowContents[0]);
        break;
   }
        var newAllsheets = newSprsheet.getSheets();
    for (var s in newAllsheets)
    { 
      var sheet = newAllsheets[s];
        sheet.setColumnWidth(2, 275);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(3, 275);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(10, 275);
        sheet.setColumnWidth(12, 275);
        sheet.getRange('A1:M1').activate();
        sheet.getActiveRangeList().setBackground('ACCENT6')
        .setFontColor('white');
        sheet.getRange('A:M').activate();
    sheet.getActiveRangeList().setWrapStrategy(SpreadsheetApp.WrapStrategy.WRAP)
        .setVerticalAlignment('middle')
        .setHorizontalAlignment('left')
        .setFontFamily('Roboto')
        .setFontSize(10)
        .setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true, '#b7b7b7', SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.SOLID);
    }
  }
}
```

I found the properties that need to be applied to the new sheets and modified the code. Good news is the format is applied correctly to all tabs. However, The execution ran for more than 8 mins and I see this message

> Executions that have an unknown status mean that Apps Script was
>   unable to determine the outcome of the execution. It is possible that
>   the execution either succeeded or failed.

Any help to identify the cause of the error and make the code more efficient will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks ahead of time

-Al

Comment: You'll probably want to use [copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range,Object)) instead of `appendRow()`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I am getting the error: ``` Exception: The parameter (number[]) dont match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.copyTo```

Comment: How did you implement it?

Comment: I replaced appendRow() with copyTo(). This might be totally incorrect and I lack coding knowledge.

Comment: Yes.  You are correct that makes absolutely no sense because copyTo is a range method not a sheet method.  Do you consult with documentation very often when you write script?...Just wandering because I do.

Comment: I did look at the documentation but couldn’t alter it to match the current code as I didn’t write it. I have better knowledge in vba but not in GAS. I getting a handle on it but to the point we I can work of cues

Comment: Well your question seems to imply that you wish the formatting to accompany the data and `copyTo` will allow that to take place.

Comment: If this is to copy a range from one location to another I may have done it myself using copyTo examples in the documentation. My ask is little complex than the examples in the wild. In my last comment I wanted to say “I am getting a handle on GAS but not to the extent when I can take the cues from your suggestion and craft my own script” but dang typos made it difficult.

Comment: We'll I recommend that you try the simple examples and study the documentation so that you really understand how the example works.  Then at some point return to your current problem and try it again.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: The issue is using `copyTo()` only works with the same Spreadsheet, not with different files. You could get some properties of the cells (take a look at the [Range class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range), the `get` functions), like `getFontStyles` or `getHorizontalAlignmenet`. You can get those, save it into a var and use the `set...` methods to put it into the new Spreadsheet.

Comment: @Jescanellas I have updated the code based on your suggestion but hit a snag with execution time and out of memory error. Funny part is execution fails after 8~9 mins with out of memory errors but the new spreadsheet has all sheets with data and format.